# MetroListView not hiding text as the header gets shortened

Tags: c#

I am trying to use the MetroListView control to show all of my data, but I am having an issue. Whenever I resize the headers the text under the headers doesn't become hidden.

https://www.youtube.com/embed/TupNNGbOj50

**I am displaying the data the usual way you would, just like this:**

```
metroListView1.View = View.Details;
metroListView1.Columns.Add("Name");
metroListView1.Columns.Add("Type");

var item1 = new ListViewItem(new[] { "Very Long Show Title", "TV Show"  });
metroListView1.Items.Add(item1);
```

Is this just a bug you have to live with, or is there a way to fix it?

Comment: Please include a description of the problem within the question itself.

Comment: I have added one more line of info, but I don't really know how I would explain this issue without writing a full essay, I would rather someone just watch the short clip to get a better understanding, this way no one will get confused because of the way it is written.